# How to set up android database relation like "has_many and belongs_to"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have two tables in android. I created all CRUD actions. But I have trouble to set up relations between them. 
So I have table Recepit which will have many logs (from table Logs).

If I create Recepit1 and it has for example 13 Logs then I will display Recepit1 in listview and on item click it must show me these 13 Logs. 
 Below is my create method for Logs and Recepit.

```
String CREATE_LOGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGS + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_CREATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+
                KEY_PLATENUMBER + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_SORT + " TEXT, "+
                KEY_GRADE+ " TEXT, "+
                KEY_DIAMETER + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_LENGTH + " INTEGER);";
String CREATE_RECEPITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECEPIT + " (" +
                RECEPIT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                RECEPIT_PLACE + " TEXT, " + RECEPIT_SHIPPING + " TEXT, " +
                RECEPIT_WAREHOUSE + " TEXT, " + RECEPIT_CARRIER + " TEXT, " +
                RECEPIT_LICENCE + " TEXT, " + RECEPIT_DRIVER + " TEXT, " +
                RECEPIT_CUSTOMER + " TEXT, " + RECEPIT_DEST_WAREHOUSE + " TEXT, " +
                RECEPIT_EMPLOYEE + " TEXT, " +
                RECEPIT_CREATED_AT + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

**Question:**
How to set up relation that table Recepit has_many logs?

Comment: You have a MySQL database running on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another table to maintain many to many relation ships :) This is how you maintain our to many or many to many relation ships in RDBMS.

As you said there are two tables 1. Logs and 2.Reciepts and both of them have primary keys :)

Now create a table called for example: LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECIEPT.
This table will have two columns. col1:LogsID and col2:ReciptID. Both are the foreign key references for Logs table and Recipt table respectively :)

I mean col1:LogsID references Logs table primary key.
       col2: ReciptID references Reciept table primary key

So whenever you enter a new log for the specific reciept you will make an entry in here :)

like LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECIEPT

```
RecieptID      LogsID
1              L1
1              L2
1              L3
2              L4
2              L5
```

So you can query all the receipts from receipts table and show it in its list view and when user taps on the list get all the logs id ascociated with it from LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECIEPT and then query all those logs from your logs table and display :)

Clean simple yet effective :) Isn't it:)

EDIT:
OK here is a query you may try :) editted your own query you pasted in comments.

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "id"; //my logs id 
public static final String RECEPIT_ID = "id"; //recepit id    

CREATE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT + " (" + RECEPIT_ID + " INTEGER, " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY("+ RECEPIT_ID +") REFERENCES "+ TABLE_RECEPIT +"("+ RECEPIT_ID +"), FOREIGN KEY("+ KEY_ID +") REFERENCES "+ TABLE_LOGS +"("+ KEY_ID +"));"
```

There is no need to have any primary key for this table :)

**EDIT**

Extra point :)
If you want to fetch all the logs ascociated with recipt you ccan write query like

```
Select * from TABLE_LOGS where KEY_ID IN (select KEY_ID from LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT_TABLE  where RECEPIT_ID = 'whatever user tapped');
```

Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: thnks cricket_007 : was struggling to format that :)

Comment: then i should have something like this: 
`public static final String KEY_ID = "id"; //my logs id`
`public static final String RECEPIT_ID = "id"; //recepit id`

`public static final String LBTR_ID = "id"; //new table id`
`String CREATE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT + " (" +
                LBTR_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                RECEPIT_ID + " INTEGER, " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER);";`

Comment: Nope buddy :)  CREATE_LOGS_BELONGS_TO_RECEPIT_TABLE will have two columns as you said :) but they will not be primary keys :) they will be foreighn keys :) There is ablsoutely no need to have primary key for this table it self :)

Comment: ok. foreign keys. But can  I use then Recepit_id and Logs_id columns form table Logs and recepit?

Comment: Please wait for a sec lemme update the answer with foreign key constraint :)

Comment: Can you please check the query and update now :) did you get it :) There is no need to change any of your existing table :) just add this table :) this hsould work perfectly fine :)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. Only one question more. So when i display recepit and on click recepit I want to show logs. I use some query from this new table?

Comment: Yes, what you can do is write select * from Logs_Belongs_to_Reciptes where RECEPIT_ID = 'whatever user tapped'; this will give you array of logid which you can use to display logs in next activity

Comment: This table's column name need not necessarily be same as their parent tables (table where they are pointing to ) just for easy understanding I wrote that :) feel free to change the name of columns :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105935/discussion-between-rubydigger19-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's something you special in java to do so, but, purely in mysql here is how you can do:

**If you have a 1-n relation between two tables:**
You basically need to add a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html) in one of your two tables. This foreign key is a column that will "point" to another table.
Always use the table with N lines to point to the table with 1 line and preferably use a unique field to create the foreign key.
Mysql have a very nice example

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE shirt (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    style ENUM('t-shirt', 'polo', 'dress') NOT NULL,
    color ENUM('red', 'blue', 'orange', 'white', 'black') NOT NULL,
    owner SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can see that in the table `shirt`, the column `owner` is a references to an `id` in the table `person` and that `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` thus unique.

In your example, it should be `TABLE_LOGS` that will point to `TABLE_RECEPIT`.
Then you can use a simple join to know which logs belongs to which recepit.

```
SELECT table_logs.*, table_recepit.id as belongs_to 
FROM table_logs LEFT JOIN table_recepit 
  ON (table_logs.recepit_id = table_recepit.id);
```

To obtain how many logs have one recepit, you can use a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
SELECT table_recepit.*, COUNT(table_logs.id) as number_of_logs 
FROM table_recepit LEFT JOIN table_logs 
  ON (table_recepit.id =  table_logs.recepit_id) 
GROUP BY table_recepit.id;
```

**If you have an n-n relation:**
In your example it means that one `logs` can belong to many `recepit` and that one recepit can have many logs.
In this case, you have to create a relation table that'll keep record of your table's relation.
This table will look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE recepit_to_logs (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    recepit_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES table_recepit(id),
    logs_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  REFERENCES table_logs(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I believe your answer was more accurate then mine :) as you were perfectly accurate on pointing out the need to have foreign key in one of the table. My answer to have seperate table though solves the issue it is more accurate to maintin m-n (many to many) relation ship rather than 1-n(one to many) But I suggested that solution as I din wanted him to change any of his existing table schema :) So upvoting your answer :)